# Kotlin Cancel Drag Action Mid Dragging

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop, draggable

If a user is dragging a button and a condition becomes true the dragging must be cancelled and the item must return to its original position.

I am having a hard time finding a way to cancel dragging once dragging has started.

my function looks like this:

```
fun beginDraggingMotion(recyclerViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder){
itemTouchHelper.startDrag(recyclerViewHolder)}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a View method for doing this:

> `cancelDragAndDrop()`

Seems to work as expected.